# Consulta SQL express - Llave foránea valor auto-incremental

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-express

Buenas foro. Espero todos se encuentren bien.

Tengo una duda sobre como puedo realizar la siguiente referencia.

Tengo 1 tabla de Artículos **tb_articulos** relacionada con otra tabla Reparaciones **tb_rep**

La tabla artículos tiene una col id auto-incremental al igual que la tabla reparaciones, he referenciado la columna **art_id** (**PK** de **tb_articulos**) con la columna **art_id** en la **tb_hrep** como lo muestro en la imagen.

Cuando modifico las tablas, el campo de **tb_articulos** se actualiza (update set ..) en el campo **art_state** (cambia el estado de stock a reparación por ej) pero el ID es un autoincremental que se generó cuando se insertó el artículo. A la vez modifico la tabla **tb_rep** para asignar el local a donde fue y las fechas de ingreso y egreso.

Lo que quiero hacer es que el campo llave foránea de la tabla tb_rep (**PK** autoincremental **art_id**) sea igual a la columna de la **FK** de la tabla **tb_rep**.

Sin embargo este valor queda vacío y no me deja realizar la siguiente instrucción pues no permite nulos.

```
UPDATE tb_articulos SET art_state='REPARACIÓN' WHERE art_snum='QWERTY1'
INSERT INTO tb_rep (rep_datein, rep_dateout, rep_serv) VALUES ('2017-12-14',NULL, 'EMPRESA_SERVICE1')
```

El mensaje claramente es que la foreignKey no puede ser nula:

(0 rows affected)

(1 row affected)
Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 5
No se puede insertar el valor NULL en la columna 'art_id', tabla 'SISO_1-0.dbo.tb_rep'. La columna no admite valores NULL. Error de INSERT.
Se terminó la instrucción.

Mi pregunta es, sin que el usuario tenga que definir el ID en ningún caso, es posible hacer que sea autoincremental para no perder la relación entre los datos, es posible hacer que se autoasigne ese valor desde la BD?

Pido disculpas por lo extenso pero supe como hacerlo más compacto.

Gracias de antemano por cualquier ayuda que me puedan brindar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si la relación entre `tb_articulos` y `tb_rep` ya está establecida por medio de la tabla intermediaria `tb_hrep`, ¿por qué defines `art_id` en la tabla `tb_rep` también? ¿Cual es la relación entre `tb_articulos` y `tb_rep`? ¿Es `N..N`, o es otra?

Comment: Perdón, sí, es una relación N:N - Cuando un artículo (tb_articulos) entra a "reparación" se le añade campo fecha ingreso a la empresa X y ahí es donde quiero generar la relación.

Comment: Entonces no entiendo cual es el objetivo de definir la columna `art_id` en la tabla `tb_rep`. Para eso ya tienes la columna `art_id` en la tabla `tb_hrep`.  Porque el tratar de mantener esta columna en la tabla `tb_rep` indicaría una relación `1..N`, no `N..N`.

Comment: No, ese art_id en tb_rep estaba por error por una prueba que hice, lo que tengo hecho es desde tb_hrep.art_id -> FK -> tb_articulos.art.id y en la tabla tb_hrep.rep_id -> FK -> tb_rep.rep_id, pero los valores en el id de la tabla tb_hrep no se setean.

Comment: Entonces la pregunta es confusa, porque el error que indicas en tu pregunta tiene que ver con la columna `art_id` en la tabla `tb_rep`, no `tb_hrep`. Y en cuanto a setear los valores en la tabla `tb_hrep`, eso no es nada que se pueda hacer de forma automática. Tu tienes que escribir el código que establezca la relación entre los artículos y las reparaciones una vez que estas llegan a existir en sus respectivas tablas.

Comment: Claro, esa es mi pregunta, si había alguna manera de hacerlo automáticamente desde SQL pero veo que no hay otra forma más que generar esos valores de la relación a través del programa, es así?

Comment: Así es. Cuando insertas un nuevo artículo o una nueva reparación, SQL Server no tiene el "conocimiento" necesario para establecer relaciones entre las 2 tablas de forma automática. ¿Cómo sabría cuales registros van con cual? La relaciones, por medio de insertar registros en la tabla `tb_hrep`, las debes establecer tu de forma explícita, porque solo tu sabes cuales registros deben relacionarse entre sí.

Comment: Muchas gracias sstan, me has sido de buena ayuda, aquí ya me estoy poniendo con el código para setear los ID a través del programa. Felicidades y que termines bien tu día.